# Knex.js subselect for 'in' clause as part of join

Tags: knex.js

Banging my head against the wall on this one.  Here is one 'on' clause from a fairly complex join:

```
on kr.id = urm.role_id and kr.client in (select id from client where client.client_id = ?)
```

I'm trying to find a more elegant way of constructing the subquery, but the best I've come up with so far for the clause after the 'and' is:

```
.andOn('kr.client','in', knex.raw('select id from client where client.client_id = $2'))
```

but I feel like there should be some way to form this using `andOnIn` and a subselect.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using objection.js and for me `andOnIn` + subquery just works. It should also work with vanilla knexjs. Unfortunately, it seems that typings for `andOnIn` + subqueries are missing, so you may need to `// @ts-ignore` that or perhaps submit a PR with a fix for typings.

```
query.leftJoin('kr`, (join) => {
  join
    .on('kr.id', 'urm.role_id')
    .andOnIn('kr.client', knex('client').select('id').where(...));
});
```

Comment: It does indeed "just work."  I was believing the compiler and I should have taken a look at the type definitions.  Thanks!